Figure in $\mathbb R^2$ whose symmetry group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z )^3$
The question is whether there exists a figure in $\mathbb R^2$ plane whose symmetry group is isomorphic to $( \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z)^3$.
My line of reasoning is:

$\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z 
\times \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/nm\mathbb Z$ and so $(\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z)^3\cong \mathbb Z/8 \mathbb Z$.
There exists a class of figures ("swastikas" with $n$ branches) where $n$-branched swastika's symmetry group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$.
We can build an isomorphism from a $8$-branched swastika to $ \mathbb Z/8 \mathbb Z$ and then to $( \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z)^3$.

There seems to be a gap in my reasoning because there should not be such a figure (Is there exists such figure $A$ on plane $E^2$ which isometry group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$). Could you suggest where the gap lies?

Actually, it is not true that $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)\times(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/nm\Bbb Z$ in general (although it is true when $n$ and $m$ are coprime). And of course that $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\times(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\times(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$, since $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$ has elements with order $8$, whereas the order of every element of $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\times(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\times(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ is $1$ or $2$.

No such figure exists, for the following reasons.
Let $G$ be the symmetry group of the figure, so $G \approx \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. Thus $G$ contains seven different elements of order $2$, all of which commute with each other.
First, one can completely classify all order $2$ isometries of the Euclidean plane:

For each line $L$, a reflection across $L$.
For each point $P$, a $180^\circ$ rotation around $P$.

Second, given two different order $2$ isometries, one can completely classify when they commute, and then we can draw conclusions.

Two reflections commute if and only if their reflection lines $L_1,L_2$ are parallel or perpendicular.

However, if $L_1,L_2$ are distinct parallel lines then $L_1 \circ L_2$ is a translation isometry which has infinite order.
Conclusion 1: $G$ contains either no reflections, or $1$ reflection, or $2$ reflections across perpendicular lines.

Two distinct $180^\circ$ rotations do not commute.

Conclusion 2: $G$ contains at most one $180^\circ$ rotation.
Putting these together, we see that $G$ contains at most three different elements of order $2$.

Ah, very strange. I just clicked on the linked question in the post and I see that it was answered... by me... So much for my memory capacity. At least this proof is simpler!
